# How to pass PHP variables in SQL query resulted from the previous SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, having, subquery

I am working on a PHP project and I encountered a problem where I cannot pass a PHP variable to execute a SQL query resulted from a previously executed query.

```php
<?php 
    include"config.php"; 
    $sqli = mysql_query("select * from police_data where p_id='$name_perm'",$conn); 
        //name_perm is again a variable that stores the police id. It works very fine.

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqli))
    {
        echo $rows['location'].'<br>';
        $e = intval($rows['location']+ 6);
        $f = intval($rows['location']- 6);
        echo $e.'<br>'; // I received the location in INT format
    }   echo $f.'<br>';

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from data_get having LatLong between 90 and 95",$conn) ; 
        // This query gives me result. But instead of 90 and 95 I want to pass $e and $f.
        // When I tried so it doesn't provide any result. 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img height="300" width="240" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['Image']. '"></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['LatLong'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['month'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }   
?>
```

The above code is to retrieve image data between some range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that, when you are passing any value in the **between** function , make sure that the first value passed should be lesser that the second value.

so in my code,

```
<?php 
    include"config.php"; 
    $sqli = mysql_query("select * from police_data where p_id='$name_perm'",$conn); 
        //name_perm is again a variable that stores the police id. It works very fine.

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqli))
    {
        echo $rows['location'].'<br>';
        $e = intval($rows['location']+ 6);
        $f = intval($rows['location']- 6);
        echo $e.'<br>'; // I received the location in INT format
    }   echo $f.'<br>';

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from data_get having LatLong between $f and $e",$conn) ; 
        // $e = 103 , $f = 91
        // so, mysql_query("select * from data_get having LatLong between $e and $f",$conn) ; is wrong. Hence $e and $f had to swapped.   

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img height="300" width="240" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['Image']. '"></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['LatLong'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['month'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
mysql_query("select * from data_get having LatLong between $e and $f",$conn) ;
```

But please stop using mysql_query, it's [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: I already used that code and tried it, But id did not give me any result

Comment: then echo the values before the query and check whether they are correct?

Comment: Did it. It perfectly give me the value.

Comment: Ok. PHP variables are passed in the way I specified. There seem to be some issue with your local settings and values. Please check for your sql query, variables, values and database etc.

Comment: Thank you @Sumit Pandey , Can you elaborate what can be those issues.  Because I checked everything. Everything is correct. Its just that these variables are not been passed. Dont know why. Because if you see my code, the first sql query `  $sqli = mysql_query("select * from police_data where p_id='$name_perm'",$conn); ` at line 3 works perfectly fine.

Comment: you are setting the value of $e and $f in loop. So for your second query, the value of $e and $f will be corresponding to the last row from the result of first query. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want. Because the first query will give me result of $e and $f in INT value. and for second query, these values  should be passed. Is it has to do something with ENDWHILE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
mysql_query("select * from data_get having LatLong between $e and $f",$conn) ;
```

Pls try this :-

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqli))
    {
        echo $rows['location'].'<br>';
        $e = intval($rows['location']+ 6);
        $f = intval($rows['location']- 6);
        echo $e.'<br>'; // I received the location in INT format
        echo $f.'<br>';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I already used that code and tried it, But id did not give me any result

Comment: Please print your mysql query and run in (phpmyadmin) or other MySQL client@JijoNair

Comment: if data available on you table pls check **LatLong** data type is int ??? @JijoNair

Comment: its float. But I converted it using INTVAL function.

Comment: please print your query and past on comment @JijoNair

Comment: I did that too. It prints the result of `$e` and `$f` . But it does not pass its value in the query.

Comment: echo "select * from data_get having LatLong between $e and $f"; @JijoNair

Comment: i tried it. Even after break I tried to print those values of $e and $f. This time, i din't even receive the values.

Comment: i got this Resource id #8

Comment: wish I could add the image. I appreciate the effort you are taking, But while is working perfectly fine.

Comment: if(empty($e) || empty($f)){ echo 'while not work properly '; die;} pls use this line before query @JijoNair

Comment: I tried this and values are showing up.     
` if(empty($e) || empty($f)){ echo 'while not work properly '; }
else
{
echo $e;
echo $f;} 
  `

Comment: please add this line in else :-  
echo "select * from data_get having LatLong between $e and $f"; and send result to me @JijoNair

Comment: finally some hope. Its giving me the values of $e and $f in else statement.  But when I tried to execute it in query. its giving me nothing

Comment: finally i got the answer.  The problem was that. The value of  $e was bigger than value of $f. Hence I just swapped the value. and it worked very fine. thank you sooo much

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$where="WHERE LatLong between ".$e." AND ".$f.";


 mysql_query("select * from data_get $where",$conn) ;
```

Comment: I tried your code but still no result. I modified it to ,      `$where = "WHERE LatLong between '.$e.' AND '.$f.' "; $sql = mysql_query("select * from data_get $where",$conn) ;`     but I still got no result

Comment: echo your query and hit it in sql command and see whether value coming or not.(check $e and $f value showing or not)

Comment: it shows me result of both `$e` and `$f` even before the exact SQL query ` $sql = mysql_query("select * from data_get having LatLong between 90 and 95",$conn) ; `

Comment: then may be values of rows not matching in between $e and $f

Comment: I checked it. If I specify the value of `$e` and `$f` statically (i.e. its integer value ) than it gives me result.